# How could you rewrite this function in just one line using infinite lists in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm still a bit confused on how to use Haskell. I understand the concept but if given this sort of Python function, how can it be written as one line?

```
def makeTupleList(ls):
    mylist = []
    counter = 1
    for x in ls:
        mylist.append((counter, x))
        counter += 1
    return mylist
```

Comment: or define it in 0 lines. i.e. don't define it, just use `zip [1..]`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`zip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) function. It takes two lists and combines them into a list of corresponding pairs. The length of the resulting list will be the length of the shortest list, meaning that you can zip with an infinite list, and it will stop when the other list runs out.

```
makeTupleList :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
makeTupleList ls = zip [1..] ls
```